# Importing Saved Object to Kibana via setup.yml

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a file in JSON format that Kibana exported as a saved object and it saves an index pattern as well as some visualizations and dashboard I want to install on a fresh image of Kibana and Elasticsearch.

Reading some [Elastic for Docker documentation](https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker) I see that there is the possibility to install Dashboards and Index Patterns via the setup.yml file. The thing is that I don't know how. I have heard about elasticdump but it does not fit me as I need both Elasticsearch instances running at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's running shell scripts through a short lived container. The Beats dashboards can be imported through that binary directly, see https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker/blob/master/scripts/setup-beat.sh#L25-L28.

If you have custom dashboards, export them and import them with curl; probably  in https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker/blob/master/scripts/setup-kibana.sh if you are using that Docker repository. You can find the API at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.1/dashboard-import-api-import.html.